# Java - working with list of objects and generics

Tags: java, generics

I have a problem with a simple piece of Java code.
I cannot determine if it solves the original purpose;
the guy that wrote it (yet unreachable) just told me that
"an object that implements `IA` should be a container (`List`) of `IB`-like objects”. At first sight I have considered it wrong,
because of the strong constraint (`T extends IB<T>`) seems illogical,
but the IDE compiler does not show any related error/warning.

If such code is meaningful,
could someone please provide an example of practical usage of such interfaces.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.List;

public interface IA<T extends IB<T>> {
    public List<T> getList();
}

public interface IB<T> {
    public T getValue();
}
```

**UPDATE 1**: added test with concrete sample classes

```
class Bar implements IA<Foo>{

    List<Foo> list;

    @Override
    public List<Foo> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    Bar(List<Foo> foos) {
        this.list = foos;
    }
}

class Foo implements IB<Foo> {

    public Float data;

    @Override
    public Foo getValue() {
        return foo;
    }

    Foo(Float data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Float getV() {
        return data;
    }
}

public class DataTest {

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Foo f = new Foo(10F);
        List<Foo> fs = new ArrayList<>();
        fs.add(f);
        Bar bar = new Bar(fs);
        List<Foo> foos = bar.getList();
        System.out.println(foos.get(0).getV());
    }

}
```

Is this the correct way to use IA and IB?

Comment: You may find it informative to look for examples of type arguments to `IA`. While it's not particularly unusual to find bounds declared that way (for example look at [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)), it is a little surprising to find such a bound declared on `IA` but not on `IB`. Unfortunately, we can't easily guess about the intent here without examples of type arguments from the rest of the code.

Comment: I can't find a practical example of such construct `IA<T extends IB<T>>`. How `T` can extend `Clazz<T>` ?

Comment: Usually if you see `<T extends Foo<T>>` it means that `T` is a `Foo` whose type argument is the type of itself. For example, `class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {}`. [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) is an `Enum<TimeUnit>`. In your example, if you did `class Foo implements IB<Foo> {}` then `getValue()` would return a `Foo`. What's weird about the code in the question is that the bound is not declared in `IB`, so this is some special expectation that `IA` has about the elements in the list.

Comment: Question updated. Is this the correct way to use IA and IB?

Answer (score 0):

As `T` is only used in covariant position, it is safe to use as it is, so the comment on `IA` can be correct. If `IA` had a method accepting a `T` (like `int compare(T a, T b)`) in one of its parameters, that would cause problems as it were in a contravariant position.

Answer (score 0):

Such a constraint makes sense in certain circumstances. For example, if you want to make an sorted list class, you might do something like

```
class SortedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

where you require that the element type can be compared to itself, which is necessary for you to sort it. (Note that `Comparable` itself doesn't have a bound on its type parameter, just like here.)

The `super` in the thing above is because `Comparable` is a consumer with respect to `T`, and so per PECS, you should use `super` wildcards with `Comparable`. In your case, since `IB` is a producer with respect to `T`, you could make it `public interface IA<T extends IB<? extends T>>` if you want to make it most general.

As to an actual use case that uses this constraint, here's one I came up with that is a class that uses the constraint:

```
class Bar<T extends IB<T>> implements IA<T> {

    T start;

    @Override
    public List<T> getList() {
        List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T x = start; x; x = x.getValue()) {
            result.add(x);
        }
        return result;
    }

    Bar(T start) {
        this.start = start;
    }
}
```

Where you have an implementing class that it itself generic (with the same `<T extends IB<T>>` bound), and it takes one `T` and generates more `T`s until it reaches `null`, and returns a list of these.

Though this still doesn't require that the interface `IA` have the constraint, so I guess it still doesn't provide an example where the bound on the parameter of `IA` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A thing I do not understand is: in order to satisfy the bound of  `IA<T extends IB<T>`, T cannot be replaced with, for example, a Float. So, why I need `x.getValue()` (which returns a T) if I already have `x`?

Comment: @AlessioBarrile: Well that depends on what `IA` represents and what `.getValue()` is designed to return. For example, when you are doing a Builder pattern, you might want the method to return itself so you can chain calls.